# NullPointerException : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, mapfragment

I'm using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2` version of Google Map Service. When trying to call the below, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   void

com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

**Below is my code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

Comment: `findFragmentById` returns null. See the documentation why

Comment: @cricket_007

this is my activity_main.xml


'<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.randy.mapspaycool.MapsActivity" />'

Comment: Post the code for fragment here. Have you used support fragment or the normal one?

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); @SriramKailasam

Comment: Don't put more information into comments. Update the question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Change this line:

`mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`

To this:

`mapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.. I'm solve it.. @Sriram Kailasam

Comment: Happy to help :)