# Adding Stripe Virtual cards to the Google Pay using PushProvisioningActivity

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, google-pay, android-tap-and-pay

I trying to add the stripe virtual card to Google pay. I am following the below link

https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/cards/digital-wallets

I wrote API for the ephemeral keys generation for the card. When I try to call the "PushProvisioningActivityStarter" the "onActivityResult" is not calling and nothing is performing.

So I tried another way, like below to launch the activity

```
PushTokenizeRequest pushTokenizeRequest =
                    new PushTokenizeRequest.Builder()
                            .setOpaquePaymentCard(opc)
                            .setNetwork(CARD_NETWORK_VISA)
                            .setTokenServiceProvider(TOKEN_PROVIDER_VISA)
                            .setDisplayName("Visa Card")
                            .setLastDigits(CardNumber1)
                            .setUserAddress(userAddress)
                            .build();


tapAndPayClient.pushTokenize(this, pushTokenizeRequest, REQUEST_CODE_PUSH_TOKENIZE);
```

It navigating me to the google pay pages. But in the end, it's showing me an error like "Something went wrong". Did anyone try the Push Provisioning API to add Credit/Debit cards to Google Pay?

I tried different ways, but nothing worked.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867143/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-com-google-android)  is similar in the essence of the error message: Attempt to invoke virtual method '...': `Looks like you are using XClass instead of YClass.`

Comment: Have you received solution for this?